# Is there a purely functional way to subscribe to an Observable?

Tags: functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, frp

I'm a long-time Java guy, but in recent years I've been trying to adopt a more purely functional programming style. I found RxJava a good complement to the ideas of functional programming, and most of my code these days can probably be described as functional-reactive in nature.
The only thing that is not sitting quite right with me is the side-effect-ridden way of subscribing/unsubscribing to/from an observable via

```
void subscribe(Observer<? super T> observer)
```

or

```
Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext)
```

In my mind, the `void` return type in the signature is already a dead giveaway that we're dealing with something non-functional (or at least non-pure) here: since the `subscribe` method does not return a value it can only contribute a side effect (which, in turn, implies the existence of mutable state). The methods in `Consumer` and `Observer` are also all `void` methods, as is the `dispose()` method in `Disposable`. So, clearly, all these methods are relying on side effects.

In practical coding, I sidestep this issue by keeping most of my code pure (i.e., a series of `map`/`flatMap`/`filter`/... operations), while extracting the subscription logic to a special "edge" area of the code, where I handle side effects like printing a message to the console or sending an HTTP response.
Of course, Java is not a purely functional programming language, so there is no real problem in implementing these side effects. However, I'm wondering, if one were constrained by a purely functional language, how would one subscribe to an observable or implement an `onNext()`? Is there a purely functional way of handling subscriptions?

Comment: Two things, I guess: 1) you can always replace mutation by pure composition, and 2) usually in FRP, the types would be higher kinded and allow you to wrap a monad like IO to control "changing the world". Cf. [reactive-banana](https://wiki.haskell.org/FRP_explanation_using_reactive-banana).

Comment: You say you defer the execution of impure actions until the edge of your application. You do that by merely describing impure actions. You can describe them by applying defunctionalization transformation (instead of a function you have a data structure describing this function) or by wrapping the impure operation in a nullary function (since Java is eagerly evaluated). This is baiscally the same that Haskell does, only that in Haskell you can only describe impure actions in IO, because the lang doesn't provide any means to perform side effects directly.